# ASP.NET runtime error:code blocks are not supported in this context-with ListView

Tags: html, asp.net

i have this `listView` and `textBox`:

```
        <table>
        <tr><td>Reciver:<table><tr>
        <asp:ListView ID="showRecivers" runat="server"><td><%# Eval("name")%></td>       </asp:ListView> 
        </tr></table>
        <asp:TextBox ID="reciver" runat="server" OnTextChanged="style_Recivers" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
       </td></tr></table>
```

the `list` the `listview` is bound to:

```
public List<Reciver> recivers = new List<Reciver>();
```

and the function `style_Recivers`:

```
protected void style_Recivers(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] separator = new string[] { "," };
    string[] reciversArray = reciver.Text.ToString().Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    reciversArray = reciversArray.Distinct().ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < reciversArray.Length; i++)
    {
        recivers.Add(new Reciver(reciversArray[i]));
    }
    this.showRecivers.DataSource = recivers;
    this.showRecivers.DataBind();
}
```

and class `Reciver`:

```
public class Reciver
{
    public string name;
    public Reciver(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

what my idea is, that when a couple of names eneted to the textBox with a **,** saperator, the `style_Reciver` function is activated and each name is shown in the ListView right away.

but it doesnt work, it gives me the error

`ASP.NET runtime error:code blocks are not supported in this context`

and marks this line:
    `<asp:ListView ID="showRecivers" runat="server"><td><%# Eval("name")%></td>       </asp:ListView>`

for starter. probably more thing wont work but this is the first thing.

how can i fix it? Thanks for the help

**EDIT:**
it works after i added `<ItemTemplate>`
now it gives me a different bug:

```
Reciver' does not contain a property with the name 'name'
```

whhat is the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List View content here should be wrapped into `ItemTemplate`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="showRecivers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%# Eval("name")%></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Update.** Also there is a problem with your class declaration. Here is how it should be declared in C# conventional way:

```
public class Reciver
{
    public string _name;
    public Reciver(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh i cant belive i forgot that. Thank you very much! something else, now it gives me the error: **'Reciver' does not contain a property with the name 'name'**. can you help me with that also?

Comment: @Cooper, error reads for itself - there is no such property. You might remove your getters and setters, and replace them with property `name`.

Comment: i though that this way it's fine, changed it and it works. Thanks! i will accept your answer in 4 minutes

Comment: @Cooper, great it helped! Anyway, updated the answer with the more conventional version of class.